# Infinitesimals of a higher order and limit

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

[image]

I read in Bartholomew Price book ("A treatise of infinitesimal calculus") that "the last term of which equality must be neglected, because it contains infinitesimals of a higher order than those of the preceding term".

In other words we can neglect the last term because limit of the last term is $0$ (when $n$ tends to infinity). Is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: As I understand the subject,  it's not that they go to 0, it's that they go to 0 much faster than the previous terms.

Comment: @Alan I thought that if previous terms tend to $\int vdu$ then last terms tend to 0 because last terms is higher order terms. Is it true?